# Can I get a simplified list of steps required to receive Google Drive API push notifications in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, google-drive-api

I understand that there needs to be a way to LISTEN for incoming notifications to my app, but I'm not sure where to begin to set that up. Can I at least get a starting point from someone with experience setting this up. There does not seem to be any documentation available anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you push the notification to your UWP app clients, the underlying principle is based on [WNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview). Then, whether you use Google Drive API or some other ways, the notifications are the same in UWP.

So, you could use UWP APIs to listen when the notifications are received. For example, you could use [Notification listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#enable-the-listener-by-adding-the-user-notification-capability).

In general, we setup a background task with [UserNotificationChangedTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.usernotificationchangedtrigger) to enable an app to listen to notifications.